# kubespray deployment Failed to download key at https://apt.dockerproject.org/gpg: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, kubespray

In Ubuntu `16.04` I'm trying to deploy `Kubespray2.5` using Ansible Playbook(`2.9.7)` command and getting error:

I have deployed kubespray many times with version 2.5 but this time only i am getting this error.
Please help to me.

`ansible-playbook -i inventory/mycluster/hosts.ini cluster.yml`

```
    TASK [docker : ensure docker-engine repository public key is installed] *******************************************************
Friday 08 May 2020  16:28:44 +0530 (0:00:20.450)       0:04:46.454 ************
FAILED - RETRYING: ensure docker-engine repository public key is installed (4 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: ensure docker-engine repository public key is installed (4 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: ensure docker-engine repository public key is installed (4 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: ensure docker-engine repository public key is installed (3 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: ensure docker-engine repository public key is installed (3 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: ensure docker-engine repository public key is installed (3 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: ensure docker-engine repository public key is installed (2 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: ensure docker-engine repository public key is installed (2 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: ensure docker-engine repository public key is installed (2 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: ensure docker-engine repository public key is installed (1 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: ensure docker-engine repository public key is installed (1 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: ensure docker-engine repository public key is installed (1 retries left).
failed: [node2] (item=58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D) => {"attempts": 4, "changed": false, "item": "58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D", "msg": "Failed to download key at https://apt.dockerproject.org/gpg: HTTP Error 404: Not Found"}
failed: [node3] (item=58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D) => {"attempts": 4, "changed": false, "item": "58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D", "msg": "Failed to download key at https://apt.dockerproject.org/gpg: HTTP Error 404: Not Found"}
failed: [node1] (item=58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D) => {"attempts": 4, "changed": false, "item": "58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D", "msg": "Failed to download key at https://apt.dockerproject.org/gpg: HTTP Error 404: Not Found"}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT ************************************************************************************************************
        to retry, use: --limit @/root/kubespray/cluster.retry

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
node1                      : ok=62   changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
node2                      : ok=64   changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
node3                      : ok=62   changed=9    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The https://apt.dockerproject.org/ repository has been shut down on March 31, 2020.

Your playbook is outdated; acquire a newer version or adjust it according to the linked instructions yourself.